# HttpURLConnection CLOSE_WAIT in case of a bad response

Tags: java, http, tomcat, httpurlconnection, keep-alive

I've seen In several answers here, in order to reuse connection, I needed to close inputstream and outputstream.
Before I closed the streams, I had seen too many CLOSE_WAIT connections.
But now, In case of a base response (for instance 404 file not found)
I'm handling the response this way

```
public static void handleIOError(URLConnection conn)
{
    InputStream es = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConn = null;

    if (conn instanceof HttpURLConnection)
    {
        urlConn = (HttpURLConnection)conn;
        es = urlConn.getErrorStream();

    }

    if (es != null)
    {
        try
        {
            while (es.read() > -1) {}
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            logger.error("Unable to close input stream", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(es);
        }
    }
}
```

so I'm closing inputstream, but still, I'm having multiple `CLOSE_WAIT` connections. I'm guessing I didn't close the socket stream, but which one? As you may know, in case of an error I can not do `urlConn.getInputStream()`

my server is tomcat 8.

Any Idea how to solve the socket leak?

Comment: I'd use another approach and use try with resources instead of doing it manually - if that's an option for you.

Comment: I found this in the JavaDoc:
`Calling the close() methods on the InputStream or OutputStream of an HttpURLConnection after a request may free network resources associated with this instance but has no effect on any shared persistent connection. Calling the disconnect() method may close the underlying socket if a persistent connection is otherwise idle at that time.`
Maybe it's worth calling disconnect ?

Comment: @maio290 I can't use try with resources, some of our customers are using java < 7

Comment: @tom1299 disconnect doesn't help (I tried), And I do not want to close the connection :(